# How to Get Rid of UNUSED Queries in MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have reviewed the previous Questions and haven't found the answer to the following question,
Is there a Database Tool available in MS Access to run and identify the Queries that are NOT Bring used as a part of my database. We have lots of Queries that are no longer used and I need to clean the database and get rid of these Queries.

Answer (score 2):

Access does have a built in “dependency” feature. The result is a VERY nice tree-view of those dependencies, and you can even launch such objects using that treeview of your application to “navigate” the application so to speak.

The option is found under database tools and is appropriately called Object Dependencies.

The result looks like this:
[image]

While you don't want to use auto correct, this feature will force on track changes. If this is a large application, then on first run a significant delay will occur. After that, the results can be viewed instantly. So, most developers still turn off track name autocorrect (often referred to track auto destroy). However, the track auto correct is required for this feature.

And, unfortunately, you have to go query by query, but at least it will display dependences for each query - (forms, or reports). However, VBA code that creates SQL on the fly and uses such queries? Well, it will not catch that case. So, at the end of the day, deleting a query may well still be used in code, and if that code creates SQL on the fly (as at LOT of VBA code does, then  you can never really be sure that the query is not not used some place in the application.

So, the dependency checker can easy determine if another query, another form/sub form, or report uses that query. So dependency checker does a rather nice job.

However, VBA code is a different matter, and how VBA code runs and does things cannot be determined until such time code is actually run. In effect, a dependency checker would have to actually run the VBA code, and even then, sometimes code will make several choices as to which query to run, or use - and that is determined by code.  I suppose that you could do a quick "search", since a search is global for VBA (all code in modules, reports and forms can be searched). This would find most uses of the query, but not in all cases since as noted VBA code often can and does create sql on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a vague recollection part of Access Analyzer from FMS Inc has this functionality built in.

Failing that, I can see 2 options that may work.

1. Firstly, you could use the inbuilt Database Documenter. This creates a report that you can export to Excel. You would then need to import this into the database, and write some code that loops the queries to see if they appear in this table;
2. Alternatively, you could use the undocumented "SaveAsText" feature to loop all Forms/Reports/Macros/Modules in your database, as well as looping the Querydefs and saving their SQL into a text file. You would then write some VBA to loop the queries, open each of the text files and check for the existence of the query.

Either way, rather than just deleting any unused queries, rename then to something like "old_Query", and leave them for a month or so in the database just in case!!

Regards,

Comment: Unfortunately, we have to provide a process diagram with flow charts that shows the MS Access Queries and Tables calling each other. I understand it is not normal but that's what they have been doing by manually draw the boxes like a flow chart in Excel. Thanks a lot